# IF Statement for Range of Cells that Contain Specific Text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I wanted to create a formula whereby it can automatically return a statement if the range contains the certain text.

Here's example of my data:

[image: Example of Data]

And here is the code that I'm using:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"B*"),"B",IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"A*"),"A",IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,{"B*","A*"}),"Both","Others")))
```

It was run perfectly for the first and second statements, but not the third statement whereby if the range contains text start with B* and A*, then it will return "Both".

Is there any way to create this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the logic up slightly by checking for `Both` first:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"B*"),IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"A*"),"Both","B"),IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"A*"),"A","Others"))
```

[image]

Another option, using `LET`:

```
=LET(a,COUNTIF(I2:O2,"A*"),b,COUNTIF(I2:O2,"B*"),IF(AND(a,b),"Both",IF(a,"A",IF(b,"B","Others"))))
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I just wanted to add an answer where the array countif is used as in the opening post: `=IF(AND(COUNTIF(I2:O2,{"A*","B*"})),"Both",IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"A*"),"A",IF(COUNTIF(I2:O2,"B*"),"B","Other")))`